# How do I fix a SQL Server always encrypted error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I had to change a column originally encrypted as Randomized.  I used the wizard and changed it to Deterministic.  I saw the error below  when I tried to update a row in my application.  So, I changed it to plain text.  Verified I could see the text in SSMS (took a back up of it).  Then encrypted it again as Deterministic.

Rebuilt my index

What I'm seeing in my asp.net application, is that sometimes I can edit the record. Sometimes it saves the record.  Other times it show the error below.  But after the error, if I edit again and resave there are no more errors.

This is the error.

> Operand type clash: nvarchar(7) encrypted with (encryption_type =
> 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name =
> 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
> 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'CCCAPX1') is
> incompatible with nvarchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type =
> 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
> 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
> 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'CCCAPX1')

Any ideas of how I can fix this.

Comment: With what code are you updating the record? Please include that in your question.

Comment: I'm updating through an asp.net web application.  ITs been fine for 3 years.  I'm using  a simple update statement.  I have not seen any errors in the past 24 hours. Maybe it worked itself out.  So,  I guess now what I'm trying to understand is why I was seeing an error showing a conflict between "randomized" after I changed it to "plain text" and then to "Deterministic".

Comment: Forget what I said, the error is still sporadically occurring.